# How to read multiple text files, add column headings to every file, and overwrite the old files with new ones in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I have multiple EEG data files in .txt format all saved in a single folder, and I would like R to read all the files in said folder, add column headings (i.e., electrode numbers denoted by ordered numbers from 1 to 129) to every file, and overwrite old files with new ones.

```
rm(list=ls())

setwd("C:/path/to/directory")

files <- Sys.glob("*.txt")

for (file in files){

  # read data:
  df <- read.delim(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

  # add header to every file: 
  colnames(df) <- paste("electrode", 1:129, sep = "")

  # overwrite old text files with new text files:
  write.table(df, file, append = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

}
```

I expect the column headings of ordered numbers (i.e., electrode1 to electrode129) to appear on first row in every text file but the code doesn't seem to work.

I bet the solution is ridiculously simple, but I just haven't found any useful information regarding this issue...

Comment: My first suggestion would be to please try and write the `df` to a different directory. Otherwise, if something goes wrong your source data might get corrupted as well.

Comment: I think implementation should work. The only limitation is to check the colnames of each data frame should exactly 129. Otherwise the lines `olnames(df) <- paste("electrode", 1:129, sep = "")` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
for (file in files) {
  df = read.delim(file,header = FALSE,sep = ",")
  colnames(df) = paste("electrode",1:129,sep = "")
  write.table(df, file = "my_data.txt", sep = ",")  
}
```